# Under TFS how do I get the build associated with a queued build?

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild

We are writing a layer that allows us to trigger a build under TFS from another application.

The intention is that a Microsoft Dynamics CRM site can trigger the build. So as to make this simpler we have written a very simple web based service that allows the Dynamics site to start the build, get an identifier back, and then poll for the status and results.

The triggering of the build does the following:

```
IBuildRequest buildRequest = buildDefinition.CreateBuildRequest();
IQueuedBuild queuedBuild = buildServer.QueueBuild(buildRequest);
```

Then we return the identifier of the queuedBuild (Id) to the client. It can then poll the service with this identifier to see if the build is still running or has finished. The problem is that while the queuedBuild does give us access to the actual build via the Build property, this is only filled once the build reaches the head of the queue and is started. Until then, this property return null (otherwise we would have used the builds identifier).

OK so I figured I'd just keep querying the queue for the queued build. Well that works until the build finishes and then the queued build is removed from the queue so now we can no longer get the build information.

What I am after is a way to statelessly query TFS to see if a build that was triggered is still in the queue, being built, or has finished. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
queuedBuild.WaitForBuildStart();
```

when this blocking call exit, the *Build* property will not be null

[More information here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.iqueuedbuild.waitforbuildstart.aspx)